# Using Autowired object in

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am trying to understand how the Autowiring works in the SPringBoot.
So, I had created a singketon class B [for example] and I was processing the instance of class B in class C and now want to use that in class A. It was all working fine. But, now I was told to use Auto wiring as my application is springBoot. So I did following

```
@Component
Class B{
 int track = 0;
}

Class C{
  @Autowired
  B b

  public void doSomething(){
  b.track = 1;
  }
}

Class A{
 // I want to use the object b in here for further processing, how can I do it ?
}
```

Am I doing it right ? Or How can I achieve this please ?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you should consider using @Autowired on your constructors, as it lets you [avoid null pointer exceptions][1] if something isn't wired properly.

If you want to autowire B into A, do it the same way as you did with C; just make sure you avoid circular dependencies.

```
@Component
Class B{
 int track = 0;
}

Class C{
  private final B b;

  @Autowired
  public C(B b){
   this.b = b;
  }

  public void doSomething(){
   b.track = 1;
  }
}

Class A{
 private final B b;

 @Autowired
 public A(B b){
  this.b = b;
 }

}
```

[1]: http://evan.bottch.com/2009/02/03/setter-injection-sucks/ <- This is an oldie but a goodie; also see http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/

Comment: It's not that setter injection sucks--it's that *field* injection, which requires reflection against private APIs sucks. Setter injection is fine *for optional dependencies*.

Comment: @chrylis True! Do you think an argument could be made that optional dependencies aren't really dependencies? It seems to me that if they're optional, the instance in question doesn't depend on on them to do its work. (This is kind of a tomato/tomahto kind of argument, and I don't really have a better term in mind, but I thought I'd ask.)